# Can you use destroyed for animals?

Tags: word-usage

Is such a sentence correct:
Humans destroyed the animal in an inhumane way.
Can I use the words "destroy" and "inhumane" in such a construction?
Because I think using the word kill is much better.
thanks.

Comment: The word **destroyed** is in frequent use. Please see ["Army dogs faced with being destroyed reprieved."](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-leicestershire-42228449) (BBC). The word makes the context clear, but if you use **killed** the animals may have perished accidentally, or in combat.

Comment: The sentence is fine, though “humans” is a bit abstract and setting off with it makes the whole thing feel alien. Usage note: *destroyed* for *killed* as it pertains to animals is usually reserved for situations where a domestic or otherwise unthreatening or well-viewed animal is intentionally (and usually clinically) put down due to that specific animal somehow becoming a threat to people. For example a dog contacting rabies is often “destroyed” so it can’t hurt anyone or pass the disease. Or a local wild animal which is usually gentle kills someone. Etc.

Comment: Argh, I hate autocorrect! *cont**r**acting rabies*.

Comment: The notorious Lord Chief Justice of England, Rayner Goddard, was once asked if it was humane to execute convicted murderers if it could be shown that they had a mental or psychopathic disorder, one example being John Reginald Christie. He is said to have replied "In cases it would be better if they were destroyed".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, that's a powerful example of the same type of the clinical distancing, agency-stripping purpose the word is used for.

Comment: I meant to write "in such cases it would be better if they were destroyed".

Comment: Thank you @DanBron for the clear explanation. Although I actually like autocorrect!

Comment: In fact you can use _destroy_ for plants, as Blake does: "O Rose, thou art sick: / The invisible worm, / That flies in the night / In the howling storm, / Has found out thy bed / Of crimson joy; / And his dark secret love / Does thy life **destroy**."